# TSQL: Divide result by percentage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to partition the result of a query in three different groups (30%, 30% and 40%).
if I use NTILE(3) function, the result are divided in three equals groups (33%, 33%, 33%).
How can I do?

This is the schema of my query:

```
;WITH TMP1 AS (
    SELECT
        Column0,
        ISNULL(SUM(Column1),0) AS Val
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Column0
),
TMP2 AS (
SELECT NTILE (3) OVER (ORDER BY Column0 DESC) AS MyGroup, Val
FROM TMP1
)
SELECT MyGroup, ISNULL(SUM(Val),0) as Val
FROM TMP2
GROUP BY MyGroup
ORDER BY MyGroup
```

Thank you very much

Comment: use ntile(10) and take (1,2,3) 30%, (4,5,6)30%, (7,8,9,10)40%

Answer (score 1):

use `ntile(10)` and take `(1,2,3)` 30%, `(4,5,6)` 30%, `(7,8,9,10)` 40%